# Android SEND action intent filter for a particular file extension?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm creating an app that has to appear on the Share menu, but I only want it to appear when the file that is being shared has a 'foo' extension (filename.foo).
I have to add that I don't know what mime type the file is and that I'm a newbie on android.

This is the code inside the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foo" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I got a waring on the "pathPattern" line, saying this:

```
App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter.
```

So I suppoused that the code actually works but with a VIEW action, not a SEND action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want it to appear when the file that is being shared has a 'foo' extension (filename.foo)

Files are not shared in Android. Content is shared. Content does not have a file extension — it has a MIME type. What you want is not supported by Android.

> This is the code inside the manifest

`ACTION_SEND` does not use a `Uri`. All of your `<data>` elements are invalid, except for `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />`.

> I got a waring on the "pathPattern" line, saying this

You had that same warning before you added this `<intent-filter>`. You will get that same warning in a brand-new Android Studio project. It is unrelated to your `<intent-filter>` and simply is annoying noise from the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me undestand android more.